# Distance between two bipartite Graphs

Tags: math, networkx, graph-theory

I have snapshots of bipartite graphs (50000x70000) that establishes a releationship between a user and artifacts that evolves over time. I am interested in understanding the change point across the temporal evolution of these graphs. My approach is the build a pairwise distance matrix and then study is further.

I am struggling to figure out apt [distance measure](https://netrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distance.html) specifically for bipartite graph, because from my understand a lot of spectral distances wont be applicable since the its not a square matrix. I want to study them without decomposing them into projections.

Comment: I see 21 different ones available in the docs, all ready to use.  Why not try them all and see which one works best for your case?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the edit distance between two graphs

Set:

dva = number of new vertices in new graph * weightVa

dvs = number of old vertices missing in new graph * weightVs

dea = number of new edges in new graph * weightEa

des = number of old edges missing in new graph * weightEs

distance = dva + dvs + dea + des

The weights default to 1 and should be left at default unless you have strong ideas about the relative importance of different edits.